# Duplicate logging in Wildfly Swarm

Tags: logging, wildfly, wildfly-swarm

I have the following logging configuration in my Wildfly Swarm application:

```
swarm:
    logging:
        console-handlers:
            STDOUT:
                level: DEBUG
        periodic-rotating-file-handlers:
            FILE:
                level: DEBUG
                file:
                    path: log/app.log
                formatter: '%d %-5p [%t] %c: %m%n'
                suffix: yyyy-MM-dd
        root-logger:
            level: INFO
            handlers:
                - STDOUT
                - FILE
        loggers:
            com.company:
                level: DEBUG
```

The Problem is, that all `com.company` log entries appear twice, but *only* in the log file. The console output is fine.

Any ideas?

Jan

Comment: Do you have (by any chance) a log4j.properties file in your project that could be interfering with the logging behavior of Wildfly Swarm?

Comment: No, but I think the problem was something similar. I have a project-stages.yml in my project that also defines those loggers and handlers. I thought that would be overwritten by the one above. But it seems this is not true for file logging.